# forgot to put regular image but it has Retina @2x image

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, retina-display

I have submitted my app which support both regular and retina display edition.

I forgot to put one of regular image file (a.png) but it has (a@2x.png) Retina image.
Is it going to be regular iPhone able to show (a@2x.png) image or not?

I have no clue since I don't have 3GS or iPod Touch, but on iPhone regular simulator came out to be show that image.

Any experience?

Thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When iOS loads an image it will check the file name for the correct image

ie. on a retina display device, it will check for `imageName + @2x + .png`. If it finds it, it will load it. If not, it will load the non-retina image and scale it.

On a non-retina display device the system will not check for the `@2x` in the filename, therefore it will just try to load `imageName.png` - if it can't find it, it can't load it, and nothing will display.

I would suggest pulling your binary and updating it.

Comment: sigh, it was school app. i don't think people like consistence update. What do you think?

Comment: Well consider whether they'd prefer an update or an app that is missing an image?

Comment: So if I load an retina image that does not have the @2x suffix will iOS know that it is already retina resolution and display it as it is?

Comment: As far as I remember, no, iOS will load it and double its scale thinking it's a 1x image, resulting in the displayed image appearing twice as big as it should. At least that used to be the case, perhaps with iOS7 and Xcode 5 this is different? You'll have to try it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but my guess is it'll fail to load the image entirely. I've found the simulator's behavior regarding hi-res images to be fairly inconsistent with real devices. You'll probably want to fix that up and replace your binary asap.