# Icon/Images (@2x) for iPhone4 work on iPhone 3GS?

Tags: iphone, icons, ios4

Icon/Images with more resolution (@2x) for iPhone4 work on iPhone 3GS or I have make images to 3GS too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to create a separate, low resolution version of all your images, the 3GS will not look for your @2x files. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786769/forgot-to-put-regular-image-but-it-has-retina-2x-image) for further information.